# how i can show my *.pdf files from storage/?

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, filesystems, laravel-10

I have a project with Laravel & Livewire, in a component i save a *.pdf on `app/storage/public/documents/*MiFiles.pdf`, save the path in field of my database ($document->content), when i apply `Storage::Exist($document->content)` laravel return True, and I can download file from this path saved, but try show this content on a iframe, and laravel show me 404 file not found.
My project runs on a local machine (127:0.0.0) and apply the asset to `<iframe src={{asset($document->content)}}></iframe>`but it does not show the file.

I ran 'php artisan storage:link' and my fileSystem.php file is configured to

`default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public')`

and .env file has FILESYSTEM_DISK variable set to public as well

the links has:
`'links' => [ public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public') ],`

But not laravel found file ¿how i can solve this?

Comment: When you inspect your HTML page where you have the iframe where does it show the iframe is pointing?

Comment: copy the `src` attribute and open it on a new tab, do you see your pdf?

Comment: @JasonOlson 
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/documents/otronuevodocumento.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-geolocation allow-clipboard-read allow-clipboard-write allow-insecure-requests allow-downloads allow-same-origin: false">
                        </iframe>

Comment: @krisgjika 404 Same error, src = http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/documents/otronuevodocumento.pdf

on my fileSystem have: 
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        // public_path('documents') => storage_path('app/documents'),
    ],

and my path on folder:
C:\samesoft\storage\app\public\documents\otronuevodocumento.pdf

Comment: @JulianRodríguez try removing "public" like so `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/documents/otronuevodocumento.pdf`

Comment: Not found the file: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) @krisgjika

Comment: are you sure your symlink exists? go to public and you should see a storage folder, check inside and find your file

Comment: i check permissions from my storage dir with ls -s:

  Directory: C:\samesoft\storage\app\public

Mode         LastWriteTime     Length Name
----         -------------     ------ ----
d----      9/24/2023 9:38 AM        documents

  Directory: C:\samesoft\storage\app\public\documents

Mode         LastWriteTime     Length Name
----         -------------     ------ ----
-a---      9/12/2023 11:35 AM    1427545 gQ4Bmevk9HKHyJkUZ9HAo8p8PuXQC
                         wJqesKA6Py4.pdf
-a---      9/24/2023 9:38 AM     52562 otronuevodocumento.pdf

Comment: @JulianRodríguez  
So if you were to go to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/documents/otronuevodocumento.pdf 

I would assume it works? And just to be sure, if you were to simply dump the value of the variable $document->content -- it would say the simply otronuevodocumento.pdf??

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It seems that i ran the ```storage:link```  command from another directoy of my projects when excute, wich generated an error in my app. for this reaseon didn't work

I should reviewed the contents of ```public/storage``` with ```ls -l``` to see if the link existed. Instead, i relied on the Laravel message when trying  to execute the ```php artisan storage:link``` command, wich said ```link already exist```.

Comment: To fix the problem, I removed the wrong link using ```rm -rf public/storage```, then went to th root directory of my project and execute ```php artisan storage:link``` again. Now it works! Im very happy in this momment, thanks a lot for help, 2.5 weeks on this issue, i don't know why not remove this link before, but i'm sure it won't happend me again.